# Ruby 2.0.0 - Remove the debugger gem installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.0

I am new to Ruby. I am using Ruby 2.0.0. I want to run an existing project in Ruby 2.0.0. When I try to run "Bundle install", it is trying to install the gem debugger, even I didn't included the debugger gem in the gem file.

How can I remove the debugger gem from installing?

Comment: It could be required as dependency by another gem

Comment: Is your `Gemfile.lock` file have this gem ?

Comment: Try: "gem uninstall debugger" and then use command "bundle install".

Comment: @jonsnow, my gem file dont have the gem "debugger".

Comment: @rmagnum2002, how can I find out which gem requires "debugger"?

Comment: @test, u need gem file? or gemfile.lock file?

Comment: @Rajivgandhi you can find this in gemfile.lock

Comment: @rmagnum2002, it is not available in the gemfile.lock..

Comment: Well then, post your Gemfile here or on gist. https://gist.github.com/

Comment: @rmagnum2002, https://gist.github.com/rajivgandhi2010/b684bc6826429f966ccf

Answer (score 0):

You can run `gem dependency` to show all gems from current Gemfile with their dependencies.

Its highly likely that `debugger` is required by some other gem in your case.